# Getting Flutter doctor to work

Tags: flutter

How do I get `flutter doctor` on my Windows 10 laptop to work, please?
[I followed the guidelines here](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#clone-the-repo),

Used git to clone the flutter repository,

`git clone -b alpha https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`,

Tried adding `"C:\Users\<user>\flutter\bin"` to my path in the Control Panel
and then in an Admin Powershell, tried executing `flutter doctor`.

At first, it just hung.
After googling for help, I tried deleting the contents of the
`C:\Users\<user>\flutter\bin\cache folder` and re-executing `flutter doctor` but to no avail.
Then, I tried deleting all of flutter and cloning again but `flutter doctor` just hung again but with, `Updating flutter tool`.

Tried a few different Googled PATH-adding ideas (that seems to be a complex and disputed area.)
Got a new message: `Waiting for another flutter command to release the startuplock`

The latest state is that `flutter doctor` still just hangs but without any message.
I suspect the problem lies in the new Path not being properly recognised (in the registers??)
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the issue is not clear enough, but this might be solution, if your `flutter doctor` is stuck, it might be due to **Background Intelligent Transfer Service** is disabled, in order to check for yourself, **do the following:**

1. Click on the **start** menu, and then start typing **services**.
2. Launch the **services** and look for **Background Intelligent Transfer Service** and make sure it is running.
   [image]

At this stage I believe you will find it disabled for some reason, just right click on it and go to **properties** and **start** the service, also change the **startup type** to **automatic**.

I can not think of other reasons that might prevent `flutter doctor` to run for the first time on a Windows machine other than that honestly.

Comment: My Background Intelligent Transfer Service was/is running and has Automatic (Delayed Start). Despite running Services as Admin, I couldn't successfully change the Startup Type to purely automatic, as you recommend. I tried stopping the service and changing to a manual start but after refreshing/restarting, the Startup Type always reverts to, Automatic (Delayed Start). Thanks for your help so far @aziza. Incidently, I'd forgotten to mention in my question that I'd added dart.exe to my Windows firewall allowed programs, as suggested by someone on the net.

Comment: Does the user directory have any spaces or capital letters ?

Comment: Capitals, yes:
C:\Users\Mike

Comment: Maybe you should try to install flutter into another directory for testing, try to reinstall it directly under C: and see how it goes.

Comment: Did that but have still got trouble.
First time I've tried this but hope this link will let you see my efforts in an admin power shell...
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzQAcIpH9iwkVllUMlQ2OU9YaVk
and that was after adding C:flutter\bin to my path.

Comment: Was this a reinstall or did you just moved the previous directory ?

Comment: (can't chat yet)
I deleted the previous flutter folder in my environment and reinstalled with git.
Despite my adding C:flutter\bin as one of my paths, it doesn't show up in the lower screen here but only in the upper. Also, the now defunct path of C:Users\Mike\flutter\bin appears twice! Probably not relevant as I issued flutter doctor from the root directory anyway, right?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzQAcIpH9iwkSlZMWGFZSGFBVWs

Comment: I appreciate the help you've given so far and hope you didn't misunderstand me when I said (can't chat yet) -
I would have liked to have chatted but wasn't allowed as I've only one bronze badge so far.
Hope you or someone else can help me further please. Will probably be online Tuesday, around 11am Central European Time.
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: There is no misunderstanding, I very much like to help, but honestly I have got no clue, why do not you file an issue ?

Comment: Wow. Thanks, @aziza

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a little bit old. Here is a solution that worked for me. Run the Command Prompt as an admin solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows user check to see if the unzipped flutter folder is read only. (i.e right click the folder then properties then in the attributes section untick the readonly property then apply this change to the folder along with the sub-folders then ok and thats it. Worked for  me.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors I got and how I fixed it:
(ERROR 1):

```
  [flutter] flutter doctor -v 'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
            Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. exit code 1
```

(Fix) - Go to  flutter installation folder and inside flutter/bin edit the flutter.bat file using a text editor and remove the line (20) that says:

```
IF EXIST "%mingit_path%" SET PATH=%PATH%;%mingit_path%
```

The code should look like this on those lines:

```
REM If available, add location of bundled mingit to PATH 
SET mingit_path=%FLUTTER_ROOT%\bin\mingit\cmd
```

Save and Run flutter doctor and everything should work fine.

(ERROR 2):

```
flutter doctor takes too long
```

(Fix) - I downloaded the previous version of the sdk it worked like a charm.

(ERROR 3):

```
 Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
```

(Fix):

- Open Android Studio
- Tools Menu, SDK Manager
- In the window that comes up there are inner panels, choose SDK Tools panel
- Tick Android SDK Command-line Tools
- Choose Apply button near the bottom of the window

This worked.

(ERROR 4):

```
  The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

(Fix) - Put the correct part in the env variables. I had put D:\flutter  instead of D:\flutter\bin. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that worked for me
initially i had downloaded the 2.2.5 SDK which gave the forever run error so i went back and downloaded the previous version ie 2.2.2 it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter SDK is installed in a protected folder and may not function correctly. Please move the SDK to a location that is user-writable without Administration permissions and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I just install flutter folder at *C:\Users....\AppData\Local\src\flutter* and update environment variables.
and now **flutter doctor** run smoothly.

Comment: I believe your path does not match with the official documentation.
You could write C:\src\flutter. It's the shortest & sweetest path for SDK.

Comment: I believe your path does not match with the official documentation.
You could write C:\src\flutter. It's the shortest & sweetest path for SDK.